# How to evaluate Ruby code in Haml as a varaible

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I was playing with [ruby evaluation in haml](https://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby-evaluation). It doesn't work if i pass a variable to the haml template. it only works if the ruby code is already inside the template (not passed as variable), I'm sharing my source code for better explanation

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'

get '/' do
  @user_input = params[:foo_user_input]
  puts @user_input
  haml :foo
end

__END__

@@ foo

%p= "hello"
<br>
%p= 7*7
<br>
%p= #{@user_input}
<br>
%p This is #{7*7} cake!
<br>
%p This is #{@user_input} cake!
<br>
%p= @user_input
<br>
```

if i pass `7*7` to the GET request, as you can see i get exactly `7*7`, where it's not evaluated to `49`. it only gets evaluated if i already place `7*7` in the haml template itself.

```
hello
49
This is 49 cake!
This is 7*7 cake!
7*7
```

Comment: `@user_input` is a string, i.e. it's equivalent to `'7*7'`, not `7*7`. Try interpolating a string via `#{'7*7'}` instead of `#{7*7}` and you'll see that it behaves identically to your `@user_input`. And no, you don't want to evaluate user input as Ruby code on the server side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to evaluate Ruby code that is store in a string variable, then you can use [`eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) like this:

```
%p This is #{eval(@user_input)} cake!
```

**Warning**: But [never pass strings to `eval` from an untrusted source](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/security_rdoc.html#label-eval). An attacker could pass code to your method that uploads our passwords to their server or that deletes your hard disk.

Comment: Thanks, so it's not possible to pass it as a variable without eval?

Comment: Everything passed from a browser to a web application is passed as a string. You can translate those strings into an integer, a date or whatever. But that translation needs to make sense (for example, you cannot translate "foo" into a number) and it needs to be safe, because you cannot trust the client. In this example I see only two options: 1) evaluate the string on the client in the browser and only send the result to the server. Or parse the string step by step to make sure that it only contains numbers and operators and therefore can be considered safe before evaluating.

Comment: There's [tools like this](https://github.com/schneidmaster/eqn) which just do math.